# Asking about ML recursive function

Tags: sml, ml

I have been doing with ml function and got some annoying things.

I will explain it with simple code.
For example if there is a list(int*int) and I want to examine that there are some tuples that contains 3 for the first element.

```
L = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(3,4)]
```

so in this list, I want to get 5 and 4.
However, in ML, the function is recursive, so if I write code like this.

```
fun a(list) = 
    if #1(hd(list)) = 3 then #2(hd(list))
    else a(tl(list))
```

in this simple function, it can get 5 but not 4 because once it detects that (3,5) is satisfied the condition it returns 5 and the function finishes.

Is there any way to get the 4 as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know ml but basically instead of doing else you need to do this:

```
fun a(list) =
  if list = nil then nil 
  else
    if #1(hd(list)) = 3
    then 
      #2(hd(list)) :: a(tl(list))
    else 
      a(tl(list))
```

(I am gradually editing this response as I learn more about ML :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call the function recursively on the tail of the list where the condition held.

In ML, you almost never use `hd` and `tl` but use pattern matching instead. And you can pattern-match on tuples for more readability:

```
fun filter [] = []
  | filter ((x, y)::xys) = if x = 3 
                           then y::(filter xys)
                           else filter xys
```

And high-order functions on [List structure](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html) is another option in case you would like to use them.